# Copy dirs and structure with Directory.GetFiles and File.Copy in visual basic 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I got this code where I'm trying to copy some doc files creating also the dir structure.

Private Sub btn_CopiarFiles_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_CopiarFiles.Click
        Dim itemChecked As Object
        Const quote As String = """"

```
    For Each itemChecked In chklist_extensiones.CheckedItems


        For Each archivo In Directory.GetFiles("C:\TestDirectory1", itemChecked.ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            If File.Exists(archivo) Then
                Dim InfoArchivo As FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(archivo)
                Dim InfoDirectorio As DirectoryInfo = InfoArchivo.Directory


                File.Copy(archivo, _
                Path.Combine("C:\TestDirectory2\" + Path.GetFileName(InfoDirectorio.FullName) + "\", Path.GetFileName(archivo)), True)
            End If
        Next

    Next      


End Sub
```

The thing is that instead of copy from:
`C:\TestDirectory1\document.doc` to `C:\TestDirectory2\document.doc`
`C:\TestDirectory1\doc1\document1.doc` to `C:\TestDirectory2\doc1\document1.doc`
`C:\TestDirectory1\doc1\doc2\document2.doc` to `C:\TestDirectory2\doc1\doc2\document2.doc`

Is copy and creating dirs in this way
`C:\TestDirectory1\document.doc` to `C:\TestDirectory2\TestDirectory1\document.doc`
`C:\TestDirectory1\doc1\document1.doc` to `C:\TestDirectory2\doc1\document1.doc`
`C:\TestDirectory1\doc1\doc2\document2.doc` to `C:\TestDirectory2\doc2\document2.doc`

I'm quite sure that the fix is kind of simple but really I don't see it...

Any of you see what is the problem with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the dir list manually, using `.FullName` to get the complete path, and the `.Remove` to remove the source dir (like C:\testDirectory) and store it into a var (`SubDir`)

Then I put together the destiny using `DirDestino + SubDir`

This is the code

```
Dim Subdir As String

        For Each itemChecked In chklist_extensiones.CheckedItems

            For Each archivo In Directory.GetFiles(DirOrigen, itemChecked.ToString(), SearchOption.AllDirectories)

                If File.Exists(archivo) Then
                    Dim InfoArchivo As FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(archivo)
                    Dim InfoDirectorio As DirectoryInfo = InfoArchivo.Directory

                    If DirOrigen = (InfoDirectorio.FullName + "\") Or DirOrigen = InfoDirectorio.FullName Then

                        'If the dir don't exist then I create it
                        If Not (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(DirDestino)) Then
                            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(DirDestino)
                        End If

                        File.Copy(archivo, DirDestino + Path.GetFileName(archivo), True)
                    Else

                        Subdir = InfoDirectorio.FullName

                        Subdir = Subdir.Remove(0, Len(DirOrigen))

                        MsgBox(Subdir)
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory( _
                            Path.Combine(DirDestino + Subdir + "\"))
                        File.Copy(archivo, _
                        Path.Combine(DirDestino + Subdir + "\", Path.GetFileName(archivo)), True)
                    End If

                End If
            Next

        Next
```